# Ionic 4 Google Analytics: Not showing real time data with no errors

Tags: cordova, build, google-analytics, dependencies, ionic4

I have followed [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-google-analytics-in-ionic-4-application-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugin/) tutorial to use google analytics. However, when I deployed onto an android device, I get an error alert that a Java exception was raised during method invocation while starting tracker with ID. I added in 'implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8"' in the android build app folder and there were no errors anymore, however there is no real time data showing on the google analytics page.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (C:\Users\main\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.21
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.21
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.21
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0) : 0.2.9

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\main\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Plugins:

```
    cordova-plugin-android-permissions (1.0.2)
    cordova-plugin-camera (4.1.0)
    cordova-plugin-email-composer (0.9.2)
    cordova-plugin-flashlight (3.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-geolocation (4.0.2)
    cordova-plugin-google-analytics (1.8.6)
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (3.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-device (2.0.3)
    cordova-plugin-statusbar (2.4.3)
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.4)

    cordova-plugin-camera (4.1.0)
    cordova-plugin-email-composer (0.9.2)
    cordova-plugin-flashlight (3.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-geolocation (4.0.2)
    cordova-plugin-google-analytics (1.8.6)
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (3.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-device (2.0.3)
    cordova-plugin-statusbar (2.4.3)
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.4)
    cordova-plugin-compat (1.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard (2.2.0)
    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview (4.1.3)
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen (5.0.3)
```

I would be thankful for any suggestions :)

Comment: out of curiosity do you have a requirement to have GA via cordova / hybrid plugins approach? I think going with pure web only is just more straight forward.

Comment: I am using capacitor to build the app onto devices, I use a mix of capacitor and cordova plugins. The app will be for devices only but there are no requirements to use GA with cordova or a hybrid plugin approach, I've just used the dependencies this way

Comment: i would say then unless you need some very specific to native features (local buffering of analytics data etc) - go with google analytics as if you would for a web app. AngulatFire package recently added the support of GA and it works well